# Request(okhttp3.Request.Builder) has private access in okhttp3.Request

Tags: android, okhttp

I just want to use the okhttp to download some bytes data, but before i finished the code, i ran into a problem that android studio report a error which said the "Request(okhttp3.Request.Builder) has private access in okhttp3.Request", my code is bellowed, how can i fixed that?

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlSpec);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    try {

        Request request = new Request().Builder
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    } finally {

    }
```

That is just some of my code, I just followed the example on http://square.github.io/okhttp/, i don't see any difference, but it just report this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in your code

```
Request request = new Request().Builder
            .url(url)
            .build();
```

you are trying to call the `Request`'s constructor method which is private. You have to instantiate a new `Request.Builder()` instead by calling the public static method. Using this type of pattern you won't be returned with the Request until the final `.build();` line is called.

Reference: [OkHttp3 Request.Builder documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.Builder.html)

Simply replace with this code and it should work.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
```

EDIT:

Also be aware that calling the `client.newCall(request).execute()` method will execute synchronously, which may cause threading issues if executed on the main thread.

Comment: Don't split up your answer in comment. You can edit the post.

Comment: I figured I'd add it as a comment since it wasn't directly related to the question and if OP was already handling it in this way was redundant.

Comment: It's ok but adding it as a note will be more efficient and OP will immediately   see that.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use enqueue instead of execute. Execute runs the request synchronously which can cause problems with blocking the main thread. Enqueue will let you do things in an async way where you can handle successful and failure responses in callbacks. Do something like this:

```
pivate String mStringUrl = "http://www.yoururl.com";          
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(mStringUrl)
        .build();
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        //do failure stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        //do success stuff 
    }
}
```